# PHP HTML DOM to parse XML second result

Tags: php, xml-parsing, par

I'm using simple PHP HTML DOM to parse XML, it is that there are several tags with the same values​​, how I can display only the second label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing from your question you're using PHP Simple HTML DOM? http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

You should be able to get the second label by doing something like:

```
// $xml is your DOM object
$tags = $xml->find("label");
echo $tags[1];
```

If you're not using PHP Simple HTML DOM, let us know which you're using, as it'll be different depending on the code you're using.

Comment: If I forgive, I'm using simple PHP HTML DOM, Thanks your response is the solution.