# how to convert a parsed data into an xml format

Tags: php, html, html-parsing

I want to parse a HTML content (web site) using the "**simple html dom parser**" using this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Parsing</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Démonstration parsing </h1>
    <?php
    require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';
    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    $html->load_file('http://grafikart.fr/blog/');
    // echo $html->find('img',0)->getAttribute('src');
    /*foreach ($html->find('img') as $img) {
        echo $img->src . '<br/>';
    }*/
 foreach ($html->find('.posts') as $post){
     echo 'ARTICLE : '.$post->find('posts-short>p',0)->plaintext.'<br/>';
     echo 'Image de l\'article: '.$post->find('img',0)->src.'<br/>';         
 }
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Everything works fine, but I would like to obtain my parsed data into an xml format. Anyone have an idea?
Thank you!

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to use SimpleXML for that ?

Comment: I'm confused, are you trying to take what you are parsing, and convert it to XML? You could just build the XML yourself since you're already looping over the posts from the HTML file

Comment: Exact, I want to take what I am parsing and convert it to XML or JSON

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php).

Here is a simple example:

```
<?php

    $test_array = array (
      'bla' => 'blub',
      'foo' => 'bar',
      'another_array' => array (
        'stack' => 'overflow',
      ),
    );

    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>');
    array_walk_recursive($test_array, array ($xml, 'addChild'));
    print $xml->asXML();
?>
```

*results in*

```
*<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <blub>bla</blub>
  <bar>foo</bar>
  <overflow>stack</overflow>
</root>*
```

Here are ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24889659/php-simple-html-dom-parser-link-element-in-rss),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872418/php-html-dom-to-parse-xml-second-result)) examples which uses *`Simple HTML DOM`* with *`SimpleXML`*.

Comment: But I want to parse the html content, then I want to export the result into an XML file, does Simple XML allow to do this?

Comment: You can parse the result from `simple_html_dom` to an array. Checkout this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25351365/4003801). Then you could use `SimpleXML` to convert the array to an XML as shown above.